# Font Awesome 5.8.1 Not Loading Icons

Tags: css, wordpress, font-awesome

For some reason my icons are not loading for font awesome 5.8.1

All files are indeed being enqueued and are loaded on the page:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-solid', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/solid.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-regular', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/regular.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-brands', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/brands.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/fontawesome.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
```

Code:

```
<span class="header-mob-phone"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></span>
<span class="header-nav-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
```

The outcome is just square boxes, no console errors and font-family is not being overwritten nor is font-weight or any other values from font awesome style sheet.

Comment: maybe they are PRO version ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif neither icon is pro version, I wish it was that simple

Comment: and are you sure the font awesome CSS is loading?

Comment: @TemaniAfif of course (https://i.imgur.com/WwKrTOl.png)

Comment: a link to the website?

Comment: Depending on what browser you are using you should open up the Developer Tools and first see if you have an JS errors. Second I would then check the Network tab if your CSS files are actually being loaded correctly.

Comment: No errors I said this... all loaded fine in network tab and site is on localhost

Comment: Works fine when I add the spans into a jsfiddle and add the four stylesheets as external resources, so nothing wrong with the code. Have you checked in a private window to make sure no extensions might be interfering? What happens when you add other properties directly to the pseudo elements, like a background color, does that show?

Comment: @04FS it does indeed, I am so lost as to why this doesn't work as it's setup exactly as should be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the `font-weight` is right. I had the same issue when using content codes in span tags, but adding `font-weight: 900` solved it.